# Ошибка "пропущены точки с запятой"

Tags: c++, массивы

```
#include <iostream.h> 
#include <iomanip.h> 
#include <math.h> 

int main()
{

    char a[100], b[100], c[100];
    int j, f;
    int i, k, m;

    cout << "Vvedite kolichestvo elementov" << endl;
    cin >> k;
    cout << "Vvedite elementi massiva" << endl;

    for (i = 0; i < k; i++)
    {
        cout << "a[" << i + 1 << "]= ";
        cin >> a[i];
    }

    i = 0;

    while (i < k)
    {
        if ((int)(a[i]) >= 48 && (int)(a[i]) <= 57) {
            b[j] = a[i];
            j++
        } else {
            c[f] = a[i];
            f++
        };
        i++;
    }

    for (j = 0; j < k; j++)
        cout << b[j] << " " << endl;

    for (f = 0; f < k; f++)
        cout << c[f] << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

код выдает 2 ошибки, что пропущены точки с запятой. Добавляю после `int main()` тогда выдает `error C2447: missing function header (old-style formal list?)`.

Как это можно исправить?

Comment: спасибо большое. ошибок не показывает, запускается...спрашивает кол-во элементов... даже все эти элементы успешно ввелись, а потом программа автоматически завершается ...в чем проблема?

Comment: @Nastena_vg а с чем связано использование древнего компилятора/IDE? Политика преподавателя?

Answer (score 2):

Обратите внимание, на какие конкретно строки ругается компилятор. Во-первых, на

```
if ((int)(a[i])>=48&&(int)(a[i])<=57) {b[j]=a[i];j++}
```

Тут пропущена точка с запятой после j++. Во-вторых, на

```
else {c[f]=a[i];f++};
```

Тут точка с запятой стоит после закрывающей скобки, а должна перед. Вообще, придерживайтесь правил форматирования кода. Одна логическая строка (обычно от начала строки и до точки с запятой; не касается точек с запятой в цикле `for`) - одна физическая строка. Фигурные скобки также на отдельных строках. Это сильно упростит жизнь при поиске ошибок компеляции и при работе с отладчиком.

Ещё не совсем понятно, почему ваш компилятор проглотил `#include <iostrem.h>` и `#include <iomanip.h>`. Правильнее подключать `<iostream>` и `<iomanip>` (без `.h`). Также для лучшей переносимости программ стоит либо вместо `cin` и `cout` использовать `std::cin` и `std::cout` соответственно, либо использовать директиву `using namespace std;` после `inclde`'ов. В противном случае современные компиляторы могут не увидеть имена `cin` и `cout`.

Answer (score 2):

по заголовку **`#include <iostream.h>`** я думаю что пишите вы на С++ (в тегах к вопросу не указан язык)

```
#include <iostream.h>//изменить на <iostream>
#include <iomanip.h>//изменить на <iomanip>
#include <math.h>//в С++ вроде нету "math.h" есть "сmath"//но могу и ошибаться

using namespace std;//раз пишите на "С++" то надо указать пространство имён

int main()
{
    char a[100]={0},b[100]={0},c[100]={0};//инициализируем сразу же массив нулями дабы там небыло "мусора"
    int j,f;  // при создании этих переменных в них будет храниться мусор
    int i,k,m;//для проверки сразу же выведите их и увидите что там "мусор"

    cout<<"Vvedite kolichestvo elementov"<<endl;
    cin>>k;

    cout<<"Vvedite elementi massiva"<<endl;

    for(i=0;i<k;i++)
    {
        cout<<"a["<<i+1<<"]= ";//зачем себя путать? сразу выводим 'i' 
                               //и забиваем в свою голову что отсчёт начинается с 0!
        cin>>a[i];
    }

    i=0;

    while (i<k)
    {
        if ((int)(a[i]) >= 48  &&  (int)(a[i]) <= 57) {
            b[j]=a[i];//в этой строке в переменной 'j' хранится "мусор"
            j++ //нету точки с запятой
        } else {
            c[f]=a[i];//на этой строке в переменной 'f' хранится "мусор"
            f++ //нету точки с запятой
        };//лишняя точка с запятай

        i++;
    }

    for (j=0; j<k; j++)
        cout<<b[j]<<" "<<endl;

    for (f=0; f<k; f++)
        cout<<c[f]<<endl;

    return 0;

}
```

---

---

---

ну а теперь поговорим о правилах в программировании

1. форматирование кода, то есть
       отступы! (aka выравнивание кода) оно то и нужно чтобы быстро
       находить подобные ошибки (а точнее не
       допускать их)
2. именование переменных и ещё много
       чего
       http://habrahabr.ru/post/172091/

вообще сразу с самого начала заставляйте себя писать "чистый код", то есть делайте отступы и разделяйте программу на сымысловые блоки, например если есть 2 цикла for (вводит данный,выводит данные) то логично разделить их пустой строкой (для удобства чтения).

Это и многое другое улучшает чтение и понимание кода, как вашего так и чужого.

p.s. попытался найти хорошую статью по чистому коду с примерами и не нашел :((

[по я зыку PHP](http://habrahabr.ru/post/38318/)

Comment: @ProkletyiPirat

     по заголовку #include <iostream.h> я думаю что пишите вы на С++ 

Даже больше. На древнем C++ ...

Answer (score 0):

Настена, ну ведь если есть цель учиться на программиста, должно же быть желание понимать элементарные вещи, которые даже не лежат в плоскости программирования - иначе зачем вам оно?

```
while (i<k)
{
if ((int)(a[i])>=48&&(int)(a[i])<=57) {
    b[j]=a[i];
    j++;
    } 
    else
    {
    c[f]=a[i];
    f++;
    }
    i++;
}
```

Всего лишь поставить ; на строках, которые указаны в логе ошибки.